# How to put a local file path in XSL attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, href, xslt-1.0

I have an xlsx file in this path:

`D:\work\sec\jboss-4.2.3.GA-\server\default\deploy\lms17.war\T422.xlsx`

and i want to put that path in `href` inside xsl document
i tried that:

```
    <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href='file:///D:/work/sec/jboss-4.2.3.GA-/server/default/deploy/lms17.war/T422.xlsx'">
    </xsl:attribute>
    </a>
```

but i doesn't work !!
any idea about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just do this:

```
<a href='file:///D:/work/sec/jboss-4.2.3.GA-/server/default/deploy/lms17.war/T422.xlsx'>
</a>
```

If you want to use `<xsl:attribute>`, then do it this way:

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href">file:///D:/work/sec/jboss-4.2.3.GA-/server/default/deploy/lms17.war/T422.xlsx</xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

or like this

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="'file:///D:/work/sec/jboss-4.2.3.GA-/server/default/deploy/lms17.war/T422.xlsx'"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```